# Rails 5.1: Globbing doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

*routes.rb*

```
resources :posts
get '/posts/*missing', to: 'posts#missing'
```

/posts/1 redirects to `posts#show`, but /posts/asdf doesn't redirect to `posts#missing`
**Globbing** doesn't work here. Why?
[image]
I'm using Rails 5.1, saw a tutorial on 5.0 with the exact same config and the globbing catched the invalid ID.
I know that I can use `rescue_from`, but I'd like to do that through routes.rb, how would I do that?

Comment: Are you missing the single quotes in the route or its a typo?

Comment: Show us that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Rails 5.1, saw a tutorial on 5.0 with the exact same config and the globbing catched the invalid ID.

I don't think this worked on earlier versions of rails (certainly not 5.0). The `show` route from post resources matches `/posts/asdf` path, and tries to render `Posts#show` with `"asdf"` for the id. That's how it's been for a long long time.

Comment: You are right! Putting the `get` route above the `resources :posts` should fix the error. isn't it?

Comment: Ohh! I thought by reversing order the error would be fixed because Rails starts matching the routes from top.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
resources :posts, except: :show
get 'posts/*missing/', to: 'posts#missing'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack-overflow . you can use this link for improve your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

EDT - just tested, and realized this might overwrite some valid routes - not sure of the final answer to the OP's question.

Order of methods inside routes file seem to play a role here.
I've experienced the same error while having (inside routes.rb file):

```
  resources :posts
  get 'posts/*missing', to: 'posts#missing'
```

after changing to

```
  get 'posts/*missing', to: 'posts#missing'
  resources :posts
```

it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this one too.  Your url `posts/asdf` is matching the route for `GET /posts/:id(.:format)` and using "asdf" as the `:id` parameter, thus attempting to call the `show` method that's wired up from the `resources` controller helper.

If you include a second slash (e.g. `posts/asdf/asdf`), it will no longer match to the show route and the globbed route will then be used.